# Styling property tag in Struts 2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I am making use of the Struts2 property tag to get the user name like this.

```xhtml
<div class="MyStyle">
<p> Hi! <s:property value="#session.firstName"/></p>
</div>
```

Now I want this div to take the style defined in class MyStyle, but it wont take any style.
What can be done regarding this?

**EDIT:**

I am using bootstrap css. The `class ="MyStyle"` was just to make the question simple. The html source code generated for the page looks like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <li> Hi! Akash </li> <li><a href="/Project/logout.action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li> </ul>
```

Comment: How does that render in the HTML?

Comment: Hi Praveen, Suppose the user name is "Akash". So the html generated is like a simple text "Hi Akash" without any styling..

Comment: Can you please send me the code, how it renders. Do you understand?

Comment: Please include the style you have used for `MyStyle` and also the rendered *pure* HTML.

Comment: Where's defined the class `MyStyle`?

Comment: Hi I am using bootstrap css. The class ="MyStyle" was just to make the question simple. The html source code generated for the page looks like this <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li> Hi! Akash </li>
          <li><a href="/Project/logout.action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

Comment: The property tag outputs... the property. You put styles *around* the property.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [bootstrap plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/) for Struts2. All you need to define `<sb:head/>` in the head tag and include plugin on the classpath. This is a typical usage

> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
> <%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags" %>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>     ...
>     <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
>     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
>     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
>     <![endif]-->
>
>     <sb:head/>
> </head>
> <body>
> ...
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

---

**Note:** The bootstrap plugin project is moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-bootstrap/).

Comment: Well I had already added struts-bootstrap-plugin jar and I added <%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags" %> and <sb:head/> . Orientation of an image in my page changed but the remaining things remained as it is

Comment: The link above include a page to update the plugin to proper bootstrap version.