# Unable to use Bootstrap plugin with Struts 2 in Eclipse project

Tags: jquery, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, struts2

I have been trying to use Bootstrap plugin with my Struts 2 project, but whenever I try to add the Bootstrap or JQuery jar file to my `WEB-INF/lib` folder, the project doesn't run and shows up a **404 error**.

I have gone through few examples in the Internet, where people have been using bootstrap in Maven project and its working fine, but mine isn't a Maven project.

This is the error I have been getting in the Eclipse console.

```
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/C:/Users/1241399/Hibernate_Project/UpgradedProjects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Infinity2.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-2.0.4.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:909)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:154)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
... 22 more

Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
... 20 more
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/C:/Users/1241399/Hibernate_Project/UpgradedProjects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Infinity2.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-bootstrap-plugin-2.0.4.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:909)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:154)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
... 22 more

Caused by: struts.apache.org - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:904)
... 26 more

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
... 27 more
```

Comment: Check your internet connection or proxy settings.

Comment: I think my proxy is configured properly and is working fine. Does bootstrap with struts 2 only work with a Maven project? Does it also work with a normal dynamic eclipse project?

Comment: It's preferable to use Maven for your project configuration, but it's not necessary, and it works perfect.

Comment: Could you please send me a link of a demo project using bootstrap and the required jar files (not a Maven project)?  I haven't tried Maven before, so I am not so ready for it.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158622/573032) the link, that's all you need to start codding, everything else you can find on the official site which is linked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example doesn't use Maven, but it uses old bootstrap plugin's version. Anyway it's looking pretty.

## [Building Java Web Application Using Struts 2](http://elizabetht.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/student-enrollment-using-struts-2/)

> The Struts 2 UI component tags are used to create the page elements
>   like the form, textfield, password and hidden fields. The Struts
>   Bootstrap tags are used for the Twitter Bootstrap integration. The
>   Struts jQuery tags are used to include the AJAX functionality of
>   submitting the form outside from the modal window and to use the UI
>   widgets like the datepicker.

**Note:** in the blog she didn't show you how bootstrap plugin is used. Libraries are outdated. may be it has the never version on [GitHub](https://github.com/elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithStruts/tree/master/).