# DatePicker or Textbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sql, struts2, java-ee-6

I am new to programming and I am working on a web application using JAVA EE, struts, jsp, HTML,

I have a table which shows some statistics and my client wants me to add a feature to pick a back date to see that dates statistics, but I am totally confused.

I had pre built queries which were getting data from oracle database and displaying data on my table on a JSP page. But now I change my query to a prepared statement and I have added a "?" to get a date from user and then replace that and make a query and display data.

First problem is that which struts when you have values to be displayed and they have some sort of problem the table won't even show up and secondly when I try to pick a date and hit submit button it should go make the query and display the table but it is not happening, I am totally lost. I will be grateful if someone can tell me how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ali. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can see exactly what is the issue that's bothering you? It's quite difficult for us to understand your issue without an example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You never get how the things done until you learn them via tutorials. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048393/573032